find 2 exact strings in same line in a file in bash
I have a file called details.txt in bash like below .
1#abc#123#xyz#2024-12-09#2
1#abc#123#xyz_123#2024-12-09#2
1#abc#123#bbc#2024-12-09#2

I am trying to find the line in which a 2 exact strings are present in the same line.
For example:
if the input strings I am passing are abc and xyz then I want the first line as my output
1#abc#123#xyz#2024-12-09#2

But I am getting below as output
1#abc#123#xyz#2024-12-09#2
1#abc#123#xyz_123#2024-12-09#2

But when I pass  abc and xyz_123 then I am getting the correct result.
Below is the code snippet of what I have done
wf_name='abc'
session_name='xyz'

# grep session details from batch_details.txt
sess_details=$(grep $wf_name.*$session_name details.txt)

what am I doing wrong here. what is the correct code.

Do you really want to find abc anywhere in the input or only in the 2nd #-separated field? Ditto for xyz and the 4th field. Please copy the first input line of your current input to a new line in the input, change abc to a.c in that line only and add the expected output if you looked for a.c and xyz in the input so we can see how you want regexp metachars handled.

Also add a line like 1#abc$100#123#xyz_123#2024-12-09#2 to show and allow us to test non-word-constituent characters in a field.

Check this out:
$ grep "\b${wf_name}\b.*\b${session_name}\b" file
1#abc#123#xyz#2024-12-09#2

\b is meant for word boundaries

With awk:
$ awk -F'#' -v wf=$wf_name -v session=$session_name '$2==wf && $4==session' file
1#abc#123#xyz#2024-12-09#2


The awk script would fail given a value of wf_name like abc* depending on environment settings and whether or not the directory you ran it from contains files whose names started with abc, etc. Always quote your shell variables unless you have a specific need not to - -v wf_name="$wf_name" -v session_name="$session_name" ...

The grep script would fail if the OP wanted to exactly match a.b instead of abc or the 4th field of the second line of input was xyz-123 or xyz@123 or similar instead of xyz_123.

If you really want to do an exact string, full-field match on abc and xyz anywhere on the input line then you could do this with any awk:
awk -v wn="$wf_name" -v sn="$session_name" -F'#' '
    {
        a=b=0
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            if ($i == wn) a=1
            if ($i == sn) b=1
        }
    }
    a && b
' details.txt

or, if you prefer:
awk -v wn="$wf_name" -v sn="$session_name" -F'#' '
    BEGIN { a=FS wn FS; b=FS sn FS }
    { r=FS $0 FS }
    index(r,a) && index(r,b)
' details.txt

or if abc has to match in any field before xyz:
awk -v wn="$wf_name" -v sn="$session_name" -F'#' '
    {
        a=0
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            if ( $i == wn ) {
                a=1
            }
            if ( a && ($i == sn) ) {
                print
                next
            }
        }
    }
' details.txt

or:
awk -v wn="$wf_name" -v sn="$session_name" -F'#' '
    BEGIN { a=FS wn FS; b=FS sn FS; n=length(a) }
    { r=FS $0 FS }
    s=index(r,a) && index(FS substr(r,s+n) FS,b)
' details.txt

If you want to do the match on specific fields then see @GillesQuénots awk script (but be sure to quote the shell variables).
